# How to set the correct permissions between development and production

Tags: permissions, sudo, users

### DEVELOPMENT

On my development server I have an Ubuntu user named `user1`. When `user1` runs `PyCharm` (`user1` must run a Django app) as `sudo` then the app at a later stage is required to create a folder `folder1` to hold some personal files of `user1`. Now this folder when `PyCharm` is ran with `sudo` is created with `owner:group` = `root:root`.

1. Why I get this `owner:group` in the folder? Is it because I used `sudo`?

Now, when `user1` runs `PyCharm` without `sudo` the same folder is created with `owner:group` = `user1:user1`

2. why I get this `owner:group` in the folder? Is it because I didn't used `sudo` and was logged in as `user1`?
3. Which process decides the group a created folder belongs to?

### PRODUCTION

Again `user1` has to run the Django app, but through the `gunicorn` service this time, which since it is a service can be ran only with sudo, so I always get the `folder1` created as `owner:group` = `root:root`.

Now since my desired `folder1` creation status needs to be `user1:user1` and I can't run the `gunicorn` service without `sudo` what are the appropriate `permission` settings that would allow to have this? Bare in mind that the user needs to delete and re create this folder and all of its children under the same wanted permissions, so a simple manual `chmod` won't solve the problem.

4. How I should configure the production account to be able to have this behavior?

I am sorry if I confused you but I tried to describe in a very detailed manner the problem. Thank you very much.

Comment: I would have thought it best not to run your app as root.  You could run gunicorn and have it listening on an unprivileged port and reverse proxy in front of that.

Comment: Thank you `Progrock`. Do you have a link or a reference of how someone can learn more about what you commented? Thanks again!

Comment: Check the Gunicorn docs: http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/19.3/deploy.html

Answer (score 1):

**Question #1 and Question #2:** you have already answered them yourself! The user who runs a directory creation command becomes the owner of the directory. When you run a command with `sudo`, then this command is (by default) run ‘as’ the super user. The super user is called `root`, consequently `root` becomes the owner of new directories. When you run a command without `sudo`, then the user who is running the command (`user1` in your case) becomes the owner of created directories.

**Question #3:** For every user there is a default group that is used when files/directories are created (leaving some details aside). It’s the first group you see when running the `groups` command in a shell. In Ubuntu there is usually a default group with the same name as the user name.

**Question #4:** I’m not sure why your `folder1` needs to be accessible by `user1` if everything is run by `root` in production. One possibility to solve the permissions might be to `chown user1:user1 /path/to/folder1` when it is created by `root`. But to be honest, this whole setup sounds a bit shaky to me without knowing more about what you are actually doing.